# github actions ffmpeg gem cannot find ffprobe

Tags: python, shell, ffmpeg, github-actions

so, we have been using a gem called streamio-ffmpeg, and it has been working well. We have been using github actions to to integration and E2E testing for our front end. We also had to add python for another dependency we are using. now, when we run the E2E suite on github actions, streamio-ffmpeg cannot find the ffprobe binary since python has also been installed on the actions runner.

we get the following message:

```
Body: Puma caught this error: No such file or directory - the ffprobe binary could not be found in /home/runner/work/folder_name/another_folder_name/server/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin:/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.8/x64/bin:/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.8/x64:/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.7.6/x64/bin:/home/runner/.local/bin:/opt/pipx_bin:/home/runner/.cargo/bin:/home/runner/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/.ghcup/bin:/home/runner/.dotnet/tools:/snap/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games (Errno::ENOENT)
```

and streamio-ffmpeg says:

```
Specify the path to ffmpeg
By default, the gem assumes that the ffmpeg binary is available in the execution path and named ffmpeg and so will run commands that look something like ffmpeg -i /path/to/input.file .... Use the FFMPEG.ffmpeg_binary setter to specify the full path to the binary if necessary:

FFMPEG.ffmpeg_binary = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg'
```

so, how can i find out where ffprobe binary is and tell github actions this information?? I have tried manually installing ffmpeg within the github actions runner but this does not help.

Comment: Donno about `streamio-ffmpeg` but I use `FedericoCarboni/setup-ffmpeg@v2` in my [Github Action script](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpegio/blob/main/.github/workflows/test_n_pub.yml) and it installs both ffmpeg and ffprobe.

Comment: i actually tried this, and, when i do, the github actions runner sort of just freezes and keeps setting up forever without error?

Comment: i will try again, perhaps i had some issue in my actions file aside from that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I use `FedericoCarboni/setup-ffmpeg`:

```
   steps:
      ...
      - name: Set up FFmpeg
        uses: FedericoCarboni/setup-ffmpeg@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Then, my package `ffmpegio` picks up both `ffmpeg` & `ffprobe` w/out any problem from the system path. Maybe you didn't include the token?

Comment: yeah that was it haha